# Javascript getElementsByClassName on multiple elements in a single row

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

is there a correct way to write this javascript code in one statement?

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
[].forEach.call(btns, function (btns) {btns.removeAttribute("disabled"); });
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you exactly looking for? Like do you want to remove the disabled attribute on an event

Comment: Why does it matter if it's on one line or two? Concentrate on making the code legible and useful, not on how many lines it takes. Also, you can get rid of the `[].forEach.call` by using `querySelectorAll`. Also, if you want to enable something, you should set its `disabled` *property* to true.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Consider making a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the section [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking another question.

Comment: Thank you all,
I am not a programmer, so maybe my question was not asked in the best way, but I was sure there was a better way to write the code I reported (always found on SO)

I was not aware of the "querySelectorAll" method which I will definitely adopt now.

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an object that's not quite an array, which is why the the second array looks the way it does.

With modern JavaScript there's an easier way to convert an array-like object to an array:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("btn")).forEach(btn => btn.removeAttribute('disabled'));
```

Or:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(btn => btn.removeAttribute('disabled'));
```

[MDN on this subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).